# Increasing the size of a subreport

Tags: crystal-reports

I have multiple sub reports in a report. On the main report there are all the same size. However, when going into the preview view for the individual sub reports some have a width of 7 and some have a width of 7.5. How do I adjust these widths so that all my subreports line up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I just needed to adjust the margins.